# Wrong String parameter when sending a json string as a post request

Tags: apache, vba, excel, tomcat, winhttp

I used this code for my Macro in VBA in excel:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim URL As String, JSONString As String, objHTTP As Object
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "xxxxx"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
JSONString = "{""name"": ""long"",""startDate"": 12345,""endDate"": 67890,""status"": ""in progress""}"
objHTTP.send JSONString
Debug.Print objHTTP.Status
Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText

End Sub
```

In the immediate window, I received this error:

> 400  Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 - Error
>   reportH1
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
>   H2
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;}
>   H3
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;}
>   BODY
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;}
>   B
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
>   {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A
>   {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px;
>   background-color: #525D76; border: none;}
>
> ## HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'name' is
>   not present
>
> **type** Status
>   report
>
> **message** Required String parameter 'name' is not
>   present
>
> **description** The request sent by the client
>   was syntactica lly incorrect.
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/8.0.28

I have not known how to solve it, please help me !

Comment: What happens if you do: `JSONString = "{'name':'long','startDate':12345,'endDate':67890,'status':'in progress'}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I solved this problem:

Sub Macro1()
Dim URL As String, JSONString As String, objHTTP As Object
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "xxxxx?name=long&startDate=12345&endDate=67890&status=in progress"
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"

objHTTP.send
Debug.Print objHTTP.Status
Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText
End Sub
```